# Left–right floating with text and images isn’t applied when text gets shorter

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I wanted to make text with the image left and then text with the image right. On small screens the image should appear on top of the text. Everything worked fine until the text is getting shorter.

How it looks with long text:

[image: Long text]

It’s working with some simple CSS for different margin on different screen sizes. But the problem is if the text gets shorter the flaoting doesn’t work properly anymore.

How it looks with long text:

[image: Short text]

Here is the code I “produced”:

```html
<style>
  <!-- @media (min-width: 591px) {
    .imagerightmargin {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 591px) {
    .imageleftmargin {
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 590px) {
    .textmargin {
      margin-top: 320px !important;
    }
  }
  
  -->
</style>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="margin-top:20px,"></div>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align:middle;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: right;" class="imagerightmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="float: left; vertical-align:middle;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: left;" class="imageleftmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="margin-top:20px,"></div>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align:middle;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: right;" class="imagerightmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Floating is working it's just that you need to read more carefully 
 https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  <!-- @media (min-width: 591px) {
    .imagerightmargin {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 591px) {
    .imageleftmargin {
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 590px) {
    .textmargin {
      margin-top: 320px !important;
    }
  }
  
  -->
</style>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="margin-top:20px,"></div>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align:middle;width:100%;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: right;" class="imagerightmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="float: left; vertical-align:middle;width:100%;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: left;" class="imageleftmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<hr style=" border:none; border-top:4px dotted #ccc; width:100%;">
<div style="margin-top:20px,"></div>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align:middle;width:100%;">
  <img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1357/3133/files/platzhalter.jpg?v=1553247050" style="float: right;" class="imagerightmargin">
  <h3 class="textmargin">
    Some Headline
  </h3>
  <p style="text-align: justify;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
  </p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to make the image and the text floating too.

This way it could works.

Change the `<p>` for a `<span>`, because `<p>` tag is inherently `display: block;`, and will not float.

Comment: If it’s just that, why not just use `display: inline;` on the `<p>`?

Comment: Because I think if you are going to override the principal characteristic of a p, maybe you don't need a p tag, anyway, overriding the display:block will also work properly.

Comment: When you actually try this, it still doesn’t work, anyway.

Comment: Remove the floats on the containers or set them to width: 100%. That's the short answer. In the long answer I would have to recommend flex, not using <hr> etc.

Comment: The tips from @KjetilHansen worked both. Thank you so much. I´m sure there is a more beautiful or professional way to solve this with flex but now it´s working and so it´s good enough for me.